# Por que tengo este error con react consultando API CON AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy consultado una API con `axios` y tengo esto Promise `<pending>`, es decir que la promesa esta pendiente , les dejo el código

```
const ConsultandoApi = async ()=>{

      const {albun} = Album1;
  
      const url = await `https://the-beatles-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/albums`;
  


        try {

             
      const resultado = axios.get(url);

      console.log(resultado);
          
        } catch (error) {

          console.log(error)
          
        }

   
  
  
    }
  
    ConsultandoApi();
  
  },[Album1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ese `await 'https://the-beatles-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/albums'`no tiene mucho sentido. El `await` tendría que estar en el `get` ya que es ahí donde vas a esperar a que la `Promise` que genera el `get` se resuelva. Cuando se resuelva esa `Promise` axios te devolverá el `resultado`.

```
const ConsultandoApi = async () => {
  const { albun } = Album1;

  const url = `https://the-beatles-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/albums`;

  try {
    const resultado = await axios.get(url);

    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```